# Twitter4j: Oauth wont work

Tags: java, twitter, oauth, twitter4j

Fighting to get a working twitter4j instance, but having problems with Oauth. I copied-pasted multiple times, created different apps and keys/tokens and still cant get this working. What could i do wrong here really?

my main:

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
// write your code here

    Tweeter tweet = new Tweeter();
    try{
        tweet.searchTweets();

    } catch (TwitterException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
}
```

my twitter class:

```
public class Tweeter {

public static Twitter GetTwitterInstance(){

    String consumerKey = "**************";
    String consumerSecret = "*************";
    String accessToken = "***************";   // yourt token
    String accessTokenSecret = "************"; // your token secre

    ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
    cb.setDebugEnabled(true)
            .setOAuthConsumerKey(consumerKey)
            .setOAuthConsumerSecret(consumerSecret)
            .setOAuthAccessToken(accessToken)
            .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(accessTokenSecret);

    TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());
    Twitter twitter = tf.getSingleton();

    return twitter;
}

public static void searchTweets() throws TwitterException{

    Twitter twitter = GetTwitterInstance();
    Query query = new Query("something");
    QueryResult result = twitter.search(query);
    List<Status> statuses = result.getTweets();

    for(Status tweet: statuses){
        System.out.println("User: "+tweet.getUser().getScreenName() + " Tweet: "+tweet.getText());
    }
}

}
```

And the error stacktrace:

```
400:The request was invalid. An accompanying error message will explain why. 
This is the status code will be returned during version 1.0 rate 
limiting(https://dev.twitter.com/pages/rate-limiting). In API v1.1, a request 
without authentication is considered invalid and you will get this response.
message - Bad Authentication data.
code - 215

Relevant discussions can be found on the Internet at:
    http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=506c3b98 or
    http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=11ed9ae8
TwitterException{exceptionCode=[506c3b98-11ed9ae8], statusCode=400, 
message=Bad Authentication data., code=215, retryAfter=-1, 
rateLimitStatus=null, version=4.0.6}
    at twitter4j.HttpClientImpl.handleRequest(HttpClientImpl.java:164)
    at twitter4j.HttpClientBase.request(HttpClientBase.java:57)
    at twitter4j.HttpClientBase.get(HttpClientBase.java:75)
    at twitter4j.TwitterImpl.get(TwitterImpl.java:1786)
    at twitter4j.TwitterImpl.search(TwitterImpl.java:268)
    at Tweeter.searchTweets(Tweeter.java:58)
    at Main.main(Main.java:14)
```

Printing the twitter factory's keys/tokens gives the normal keys/tokens as expected without weird characters or spaces or whatever. Any help will be really really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Problem was that `tf.getSingleton()` does not return a `twitter` instance apparently.

it should be just `Twitter twitter = tf.getInstance();` and then it works.

Answer (score -1):

Your code appears to be cut and pasted from known working code. Check again that there are no extra characters, such as a space at the end of a string.

Comment: Lol dude, yes is "cut and pasted" from the twitter4j documentation . And if you actually read my problem description you would see that i have already checked for extra characters in the credentials strings. Thanks for your enlighting message